# Content type creation with table of fields

Tags: entities, features

I want to be able to create a content type with a number of fields (naturally). One section of the content type needs to be like the attached image with the ability to:

 - group items together (e.g. an 'ingredient' in a recipe' - "2 cups flour, sifted" 

 - link (via autocomplete) to existing nodes [INGREDIENT NAME field below]

 - add multiple items with a "more" button

Below is a screenshot from the 'Recipe' module. Is it possible to create this structure with CCK and can this be then added in a feature? 
[image: content group]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) to make a group of fields, then set that group to unlimited entries, simple.

Comment: thanks that worked a treat! I also used field_collection_table to make adding content easier

Comment: needed to apply this patch to field_collection_table to make it work correctly - https://www.drupal.org/node/2104475

Comment: Good work! Did you need to add the extra bracket as per comment #12?  If so it would be useful to let others know on that thread that you found the comment to be correct.

Comment: yeah extra bracket is needed.